# How to get the audio file/URL total duration using audio_service package?

Tags: flutter

I am using just_audio & audio_service packages to implement a playlist music player, I am facing an issue with getting the total duration of each audio file/URL, I didn't pass duration to "MediaItem instance", so how to get duration without pass the duration to MediaItem.

I will add duration as null or didn't initialize it.

```
MediaItem(
            id: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3',
            album: "Science Friday",
            title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
            artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
            // duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5739820,
or
duration: null
    ),
          ),
```

Example:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:audio_service_example/common.dart';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

// You might want to provide this using dependency injection rather than a
// global variable.
late AudioPlayerHandler _audioHandler;

Future<void> main() async {
  _audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => AudioPlayerHandlerImpl(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.myapp.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/// The app widget
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Audio Service Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MainScreen3(),
    );
  }
}

/// The main screen.
class MainScreen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream<Duration> get _bufferedPositionStream => _audioHandler.playbackState
      .map((state) => state.bufferedPosition)
      .distinct();
  Stream<Duration?> get _durationStream =>
      _audioHandler.mediaItem.map((item) => item?.duration).distinct();
  Stream<PositionData> get _positionDataStream =>
      Rx.combineLatest3<Duration, Duration, Duration?, PositionData>(
          AudioService.position,
          _bufferedPositionStream,
          _durationStream,
          (position, bufferedPosition, duration) => PositionData(
              position, bufferedPosition, duration ?? Duration.zero));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // MediaItem display
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<MediaItem?>(
                stream: _audioHandler.mediaItem,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  final mediaItem = snapshot.data;
                  if (mediaItem == null) return const SizedBox();
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      if (mediaItem.artUri != null)
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Image.network('${mediaItem.artUri!}'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      Text(mediaItem.album ?? '',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                      Text(mediaItem.title),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            // Playback controls
            ControlButtons(_audioHandler),
            // A seek bar.
            StreamBuilder<PositionData>(
              stream: _positionDataStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final positionData = snapshot.data ??
                    PositionData(Duration.zero, Duration.zero, Duration.zero);
                return SeekBar(
                  duration: positionData.duration,
                  position: positionData.position,
                  onChangeEnd: (newPosition) {
                    _audioHandler.seek(newPosition);
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            // Repeat/shuffle controls
            Row(
              children: [
                StreamBuilder<AudioServiceRepeatMode>(
                  stream: _audioHandler.playbackState
                      .map((state) => state.repeatMode)
                      .distinct(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final repeatMode =
                        snapshot.data ?? AudioServiceRepeatMode.none;
                    const icons = [
                      Icon(Icons.repeat, color: Colors.grey),
                      Icon(Icons.repeat, color: Colors.orange),
                      Icon(Icons.repeat_one, color: Colors.orange),
                    ];
                    const cycleModes = [
                      AudioServiceRepeatMode.none,
                      AudioServiceRepeatMode.all,
                      AudioServiceRepeatMode.one,
                    ];
                    final index = cycleModes.indexOf(repeatMode);
                    return IconButton(
                      icon: icons[index],
                      onPressed: () {
                        _audioHandler.setRepeatMode(cycleModes[
                            (cycleModes.indexOf(repeatMode) + 1) %
                                cycleModes.length]);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Playlist",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                StreamBuilder<bool>(
                  stream: _audioHandler.playbackState
                      .map((state) =>
                          state.shuffleMode == AudioServiceShuffleMode.all)
                      .distinct(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final shuffleModeEnabled = snapshot.data ?? false;
                    return IconButton(
                      icon: shuffleModeEnabled
                          ? const Icon(Icons.shuffle, color: Colors.orange)
                          : const Icon(Icons.shuffle, color: Colors.grey),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final enable = !shuffleModeEnabled;
                        await _audioHandler.setShuffleMode(enable
                            ? AudioServiceShuffleMode.all
                            : AudioServiceShuffleMode.none);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // Playlist
            Container(
              height: 240.0,
              child: StreamBuilder<QueueState>(
                stream: _audioHandler.queueState,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  final queueState = snapshot.data ?? QueueState.empty;
                  final queue = queueState.queue;
                  return ReorderableListView(
                    onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex--;
                      _audioHandler.moveQueueItem(oldIndex, newIndex);
                    },
                    children: [
                      for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
                        Dismissible(
                          key: ValueKey(queue[i].id),
                          background: Container(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onDismissed: (dismissDirection) {
                            _audioHandler.removeQueueItemAt(i);
                          },
                          child: Material(
                            color: i == queueState.queueIndex
                                ? Colors.grey.shade300
                                : null,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(queue[i].title),
                              onTap: () => _audioHandler.skipToQueueItem(i),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ControlButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final AudioPlayerHandler audioHandler;

  ControlButtons(this.audioHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
          onPressed: () {
            showSliderDialog(
              context: context,
              title: "Adjust volume",
              divisions: 10,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 1.0,
              value: audioHandler.volume.value,
              stream: audioHandler.volume,
              onChanged: audioHandler.setVolume,
            );
          },
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QueueState>(
          stream: audioHandler.queueState,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final queueState = snapshot.data ?? QueueState.empty;
            return IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
              onPressed:
                  queueState.hasPrevious ? audioHandler.skipToPrevious : null,
            );
          },
        ),
        StreamBuilder<PlaybackState>(
          stream: audioHandler.playbackState,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final playbackState = snapshot.data;
            final processingState = playbackState?.processingState;
            final playing = playbackState?.playing;
            if (processingState == AudioProcessingState.loading ||
                processingState == AudioProcessingState.buffering) {
              return Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: 64.0,
                height: 64.0,
                child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (playing != true) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: audioHandler.play,
              );
            } else {
              return IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: audioHandler.pause,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QueueState>(
          stream: audioHandler.queueState,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final queueState = snapshot.data ?? QueueState.empty;
            return IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
              onPressed: queueState.hasNext ? audioHandler.skipToNext : null,
            );
          },
        ),
        StreamBuilder<double>(
          stream: audioHandler.speed,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => IconButton(
            icon: Text("${snapshot.data?.toStringAsFixed(1)}x",
                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onPressed: () {
              showSliderDialog(
                context: context,
                title: "Adjust speed",
                divisions: 10,
                min: 0.5,
                max: 1.5,
                value: audioHandler.speed.value,
                stream: audioHandler.speed,
                onChanged: audioHandler.setSpeed,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class QueueState {
  static final QueueState empty =
      const QueueState([], 0, [], AudioServiceRepeatMode.none);

  final List<MediaItem> queue;
  final int? queueIndex;
  final List<int>? shuffleIndices;
  final AudioServiceRepeatMode repeatMode;

  const QueueState(
      this.queue, this.queueIndex, this.shuffleIndices, this.repeatMode);

  bool get hasPrevious =>
      repeatMode != AudioServiceRepeatMode.none || (queueIndex ?? 0) > 0;
  bool get hasNext =>
      repeatMode != AudioServiceRepeatMode.none ||
      (queueIndex ?? 0) + 1 < queue.length;

  List<int> get indices =>
      shuffleIndices ?? List.generate(queue.length, (i) => i);
}

/// An [AudioHandler] for playing a list of podcast episodes.
///
/// This class exposes the interface and not the implementation.
abstract class AudioPlayerHandler implements AudioHandler {
  Stream<QueueState> get queueState;
  Future<void> moveQueueItem(int currentIndex, int newIndex);
  ValueStream<double> get volume;
  Future<void> setVolume(double volume);
  ValueStream<double> get speed;
}

/// The implementation of [AudioPlayerHandler].
///
/// This handler is backed by a just_audio player. The player's effective
/// sequence is mapped onto the handler's queue, and the player's state is
/// mapped onto the handler's state.
class AudioPlayerHandlerImpl extends BaseAudioHandler
    with SeekHandler
    implements AudioPlayerHandler {
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final BehaviorSubject<List<MediaItem>> _recentSubject =
      BehaviorSubject.seeded(<MediaItem>[]);
  final _mediaLibrary = MediaLibrary();
  final _player = AudioPlayer();
  final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);
  @override
  final BehaviorSubject<double> volume = BehaviorSubject.seeded(1.0);
  @override
  final BehaviorSubject<double> speed = BehaviorSubject.seeded(1.0);
  final _mediaItemExpando = Expando<MediaItem>();

  /// A stream of the current effective sequence from just_audio.
  Stream<List<IndexedAudioSource>> get _effectiveSequence => Rx.combineLatest3<
              List<IndexedAudioSource>?,
              List<int>?,
              bool,
              List<IndexedAudioSource>?>(_player.sequenceStream,
          _player.shuffleIndicesStream, _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream,
          (sequence, shuffleIndices, shuffleModeEnabled) {
        if (sequence == null) return [];
        if (!shuffleModeEnabled) return sequence;
        if (shuffleIndices == null) return null;
        if (shuffleIndices.length != sequence.length) return null;
        return shuffleIndices.map((i) => sequence[i]).toList();
      }).whereType<List<IndexedAudioSource>>();

  /// Computes the effective queue index taking shuffle mode into account.
  int? getQueueIndex(
      int? currentIndex, bool shuffleModeEnabled, List<int>? shuffleIndices) {
    final effectiveIndices = _player.effectiveIndices ?? [];
    final shuffleIndicesInv = List.filled(effectiveIndices.length, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < effectiveIndices.length; i++) {
      shuffleIndicesInv[effectiveIndices[i]] = i;
    }
    return (shuffleModeEnabled &&
            ((currentIndex ?? 0) < shuffleIndicesInv.length))
        ? shuffleIndicesInv[currentIndex ?? 0]
        : currentIndex;
  }

  /// A stream reporting the combined state of the current queue and the current
  /// media item within that queue.
  @override
  Stream<QueueState> get queueState =>
      Rx.combineLatest3<List<MediaItem>, PlaybackState, List<int>, QueueState>(
          queue,
          playbackState,
          _player.shuffleIndicesStream.whereType<List<int>>(),
          (queue, playbackState, shuffleIndices) => QueueState(
                queue,
                playbackState.queueIndex,
                playbackState.shuffleMode == AudioServiceShuffleMode.all
                    ? shuffleIndices
                    : null,
                playbackState.repeatMode,
              )).where((state) =>
          state.shuffleIndices == null ||
          state.queue.length == state.shuffleIndices!.length);

  @override
  Future<void> setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode mode) async {
    final enabled = mode == AudioServiceShuffleMode.all;
    if (enabled) {
      await _player.shuffle();
    }
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(shuffleMode: mode));
    await _player.setShuffleModeEnabled(enabled);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode repeatMode) async {
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(repeatMode: repeatMode));
    await _player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.values[repeatMode.index]);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setSpeed(double speed) async {
    this.speed.add(speed);
    await _player.setSpeed(speed);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setVolume(double volume) async {
    this.volume.add(volume);
    await _player.setVolume(volume);
  }

  AudioPlayerHandlerImpl() {
    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
    // Broadcast speed changes. Debounce so that we don't flood the notification
    // with updates.
    speed.debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 250)).listen((speed) {
      playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(speed: speed));
    });
    // Load and broadcast the initial queue
    await updateQueue(_mediaLibrary.items[MediaLibrary.albumsRootId]!);
    // For Android 11, record the most recent item so it can be resumed.
    mediaItem
        .whereType<MediaItem>()
        .listen((item) => _recentSubject.add([item]));
    // Broadcast media item changes.
    Rx.combineLatest4<int?, List<MediaItem>, bool, List<int>?, MediaItem?>(
        _player.currentIndexStream,
        queue,
        _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream,
        _player.shuffleIndicesStream,
        (index, queue, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices) {
      final queueIndex =
          getQueueIndex(index, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices);
      return (queueIndex != null && queueIndex < queue.length)
          ? queue[queueIndex]
          : null;
    }).whereType<MediaItem>().distinct().listen(mediaItem.add);
    // Propagate all events from the audio player to AudioService clients.
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen(_broadcastState);
    _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream
        .listen((enabled) => _broadcastState(_player.playbackEvent));
    // In this example, the service stops when reaching the end.
    _player.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state == ProcessingState.completed) {
        stop();
        _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: 0);
      }
    });
    // Broadcast the current queue.
    _effectiveSequence
        .map((sequence) =>
            sequence.map((source) => _mediaItemExpando[source]!).toList())
        .pipe(queue);
    // Load the playlist.
    _playlist.addAll(queue.value.map(_itemToSource).toList());
    await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);
  }

  AudioSource _itemToSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    final audioSource = AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(mediaItem.id));
    _mediaItemExpando[audioSource] = mediaItem;
    return audioSource;
  }

  List<AudioSource> _itemsToSources(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) =>
      mediaItems.map(_itemToSource).toList();

  @override
  Future<List<MediaItem>> getChildren(String parentMediaId,
      [Map<String, dynamic>? options]) async {
    switch (parentMediaId) {
      case AudioService.recentRootId:
        // When the user resumes a media session, tell the system what the most
        // recently played item was.
        return _recentSubject.value;
      default:
        // Allow client to browse the media library.
        return _mediaLibrary.items[parentMediaId]!;
    }
  }

  @override
  ValueStream<Map<String, dynamic>> subscribeToChildren(String parentMediaId) {
    switch (parentMediaId) {
      case AudioService.recentRootId:
        final stream = _recentSubject.map((_) => <String, dynamic>{});
        return _recentSubject.hasValue
            ? stream.shareValueSeeded(<String, dynamic>{})
            : stream.shareValue();
      default:
        return Stream.value(_mediaLibrary.items[parentMediaId])
            .map((_) => <String, dynamic>{})
            .shareValue();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    await _playlist.add(_itemToSource(mediaItem));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItems(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) async {
    await _playlist.addAll(_itemsToSources(mediaItems));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> insertQueueItem(int index, MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    await _playlist.insert(index, _itemToSource(mediaItem));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateQueue(List<MediaItem> newQueue) async {
    await _playlist.clear();
    await _playlist.addAll(_itemsToSources(newQueue));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    final index = queue.value.indexWhere((item) => item.id == mediaItem.id);
    _mediaItemExpando[_player.sequence![index]] = mediaItem;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> removeQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    final index = queue.value.indexOf(mediaItem);
    await _playlist.removeAt(index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> moveQueueItem(int currentIndex, int newIndex) async {
    await _playlist.move(currentIndex, newIndex);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToNext() => _player.seekToNext();

  @override
  Future<void> skipToPrevious() => _player.seekToPrevious();

  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) async {
    if (index < 0 || index >= _playlist.children.length) return;
    // This jumps to the beginning of the queue item at [index].
    _player.seek(Duration.zero,
        index: _player.shuffleModeEnabled
            ? _player.shuffleIndices![index]
            : index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    await _player.stop();
    await playbackState.firstWhere(
        (state) => state.processingState == AudioProcessingState.idle);
  }

  /// Broadcasts the current state to all clients.
  void _broadcastState(PlaybackEvent event) {
    final playing = _player.playing;
    final queueIndex = getQueueIndex(
        event.currentIndex, _player.shuffleModeEnabled, _player.shuffleIndices);
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
        if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.skipToNext,
      ],
      systemActions: const {
        MediaAction.seek,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      },
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: const {
        ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
        ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
        ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
        ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
        ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
      }[_player.processingState]!,
      playing: playing,
      updatePosition: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
      queueIndex: queueIndex,
    ));
  }
}

/// Provides access to a library of media items. In your app, this could come
/// from a database or web service.
class MediaLibrary {
  static const albumsRootId = 'albums';

  final items = <String, List<MediaItem>>{
    AudioService.browsableRootId: const [
      MediaItem(
        id: albumsRootId,
        title: "Albums",
        playable: false,
      ),
    ],
    albumsRootId: [
      MediaItem(
        id: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3',
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
        artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
        artUri: Uri.parse(
            'https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg'),
      ),
      MediaItem(
        id: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri201711241.mp3',
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "From Cat Rheology To Operatic Incompetence",
        artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2856950),
        artUri: Uri.parse(
            'https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg'),
      ),
      MediaItem(
        id: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri202011274.mp3',
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "Laugh Along At Home With The Ig Nobel Awards",
        artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1791883),
        artUri: Uri.parse(
            'https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg'),
      ),
    ],
  };
}
```

Comment: How to do yo manage to get the total duration. I am also need this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `AudioSource` is supplied into `AudioPlayer`, AudioPlayer will return its total duration through `durationStream`.

You can simply listen to this `durationStream` and copy `mediaItem` with the duration received from durationStream before you sink it into your mediaItem stream of `AudioHandler`.

In the example, you can change the part where you sink `MediaItem` to mediaItem stream in the `_init` method on line 475 like below.

Before:

```
    // Broadcast media item changes.
    Rx.combineLatest4<int?, List<MediaItem>, bool, List<int>?, MediaItem?>(
        _player.currentIndexStream,
        queue,
        _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream,
        _player.shuffleIndicesStream,
        (index, queue, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices) {
      final queueIndex =
          getQueueIndex(index, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices);
      return (queueIndex != null && queueIndex < queue.length)
          ? queue[queueIndex]
          : null;
    }).whereType<MediaItem>().distinct().listen(mediaItem.add);
```

After:

```dart
    // Broadcast media item changes.
    Rx.combineLatest5<int?, List<MediaItem>, bool, List<int>?, Duration?,
            MediaItem?>(
        _player.currentIndexStream,
        queue,
        _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream,
        _player.shuffleIndicesStream,
        _player.durationStream, // <- add listening to durationStream here
        (index, queue, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices, duration) {
      final queueIndex =
          getQueueIndex(index, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices);
      return (queueIndex != null && queueIndex < queue.length)
          ? queue[queueIndex].copyWith(duration: duration) // <- sink mediaItem provided with duration
          : null;
    }).whereType<MediaItem>().distinct().listen(mediaItem.add);
```

Comment: This some how works but I am facing an issue. Current `position duration` is greater than the `total duration`.

Comment: I have added this code but I don't get duration for first track. But if I click next button, then duration is showing. Here is my sample code https://github.com/alexaung/audio_service_playlist Can you help me to check why it is not working.

Comment: @Sho seek bar position not changing while playing an 'http' url link.Any solution for http links??